# What is the best way for me to iterate over this dataset to return all matching values from another key value pair if I match a separate key?

Tags: python, dictionary-comprehension

I want to be able to search through this list (see bottom of post) of dicts (I think that is what this particular arrangement is called) to search for an ['address'] that matches '0xd2'. If that match is found, I want to return/print all the corresponding ['id']s.

So in this case I would like to return:
632, 315, 432, 100

I'm able to extract individual values like this:

```
none = None
print(my_dict['result'][2]["id"])
```

> 432

I'm struggling with how to get a loop to do this properly.

```
{
  "total": 4,
  "page": 0,
  "page_size": 100,
  "result": [
    {
      "address": "0xd2",
      "id": "632",
      "amount": "1",
      "name": "Avengers",
      "group": "Marvel",
      "uri": "https://google.com/",
      "metadata": null,
      "synced_at": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z",
      "last_sync": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z"
    },
    {
      "address": "0xd2",
      "id": "315",
      "amount": "1",
      "name": "Avengers",
      "group": "Marvel",
      "uri": "https://google.com/",
      "metadata": null,
      "synced_at": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z",
      "last_sync": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z"
    },
    {
      "address": "0xd2",
      "id": "432",
      "amount": "1",
      "name": "Avengers",
      "group": "Marvel",
      "uri": "https://google.com/",
      "metadata": null,
      "synced_at": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z",
      "last_sync": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z"
    },
{
      "address": "0x44",
      "id": "100",
      "amount": "1",
      "name": "Suicide Squad",
      "group": "DC",
      "uri": "https://google.com/",
      "metadata": null,
      "synced_at": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z",
      "last_sync": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z"
    }
  ],
  "status": "SYNCED"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try list comprehension:

```py
[res["id"] for res in my_dict["result"] if res["address"] == "0xd2"]
```

If you'd like to use a for loop:

```py
l = []
for res in my_dict["result"]:
    if res["address"] == "0xd2":
        l.append(res["id"])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list comprehension.

```
import json

json_string = """{
  "total": 4,
  "page": 0,
  "page_size": 100,
  "result": [
    {
      "address": "0xd2",
      "id": "632",
      "amount": "1",
      "name": "Avengers",
      "group": "Marvel",
      "uri": "https://google.com/",
      "metadata": null,
      "synced_at": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z",
      "last_sync": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z"
    },
    {
      "address": "0xd2",
      "id": "315",
      "amount": "1",
      "name": "Avengers",
      "group": "Marvel",
      "uri": "https://google.com/",
      "metadata": null,
      "synced_at": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z",
      "last_sync": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z"
    },
    {
      "address": "0xd2",
      "id": "432",
      "amount": "1",
      "name": "Avengers",
      "group": "Marvel",
      "uri": "https://google.com/",
      "metadata": null,
      "synced_at": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z",
      "last_sync": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z"
    },
{
      "address": "0x44",
      "id": "100",
      "amount": "1",
      "name": "Suicide Squad",
      "group": "DC",
      "uri": "https://google.com/",
      "metadata": null,
      "synced_at": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z",
      "last_sync": "2022-05-26T22:52:34.113Z"
    }
  ],
  "status": "SYNCED"
}"""

json_dict = json.loads(json_string)

result = [elem['id'] for elem in json_dict['result'] if elem['address'] == '0xd2']

print(result)
```

Output:

```
['632', '315', '432']
```

Answer (score 0):

This would store the associated ids in the list:

```
ids=[]
for r in dataset.get('result'):
    if r.get('address')=='0xd2':
        ids.append(r.get('id'))
```